# How to find the electric field at a point based on a uniformly charged surface

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, integration

What is the general solution to finding the electric field at a point based on some (or multiple) charged surfaces. I know that we can perform a line/surface integral if a charge is close to a wire or a surface. Furthermore, seeing as the surface is uniformly charged, we can use a Gaussian surface to eliminate the integral and write it as:

$$ E_{point} = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0 R} $$

Where $ \lambda $ is the constant charge and $ R $ is the distance of that charge from the wire.

Does this formula change when we have a charged *surface* instead of a wire? And what if there is more than one wire/surface acting on the charge? Are these formulas additive?

Comment: Is the "surface" an infinite charged plain?

Comment: If it is as Maksim asked an infinite charged plain, you can use the [method of image charges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges). The infinite plain will be a mirror, just put another charge of the opposite sign at double the distance from the infinite plain.